# Regex to select all URLs in a body of text except a particular URL (Sublime Text)

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following example of copy that I wish to do a find and replace in Sublime using Regex. However I cannot figure out how to select all the URLs except for a particular one. I know I can do it quite easily if I knew what the url was however the only URL I know of is the one I don't wish to replace with anchor tags.

Copy Example:

> this is **example.com.au** and this is *exampleflowers.com.au* and of
>   course another **anotherexample.com.au/terms.html**, url. Oh no
>   *exampleflowers.com.au* is in this sentence again.

Ulimately I want any URL to be surrounded by a href tag except a URL which contains flowers.com.au in it!

My current simple Regex I use to test for URL is:

```
    /\w+(\.[^\s,\.^#]+)+/gi
```

I have also tried

```
    /\w+(?!flowers)(\.[^\s,\.^#]+)+/gi
```

Any assistance is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex will match 1+ word characters `\w+` and then repeats 1+ times a capturing group `(\.[^\s,\.^#]+)+` which itself will match a dot and 1+ times what is in the character class.

The negative lookahead `(?!flowers)` will check at the end of matching 1+ word characters if `flowers` is not on the right which will be true because it has already matched all the word characters including flowers.

You might use your regex in combination with a negative lookahead to check if what is on the right does not contain `flowers.com.au`

**Find**

`(?<!\S)(?!\S*flowers\.com\.au)(\w+(?:\.[^\s,.#]+)+)`

**Replace**

`<a href="$1">$1</a>`

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind to assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace character
- `(?!\S*flowers\.com\.au)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not 0+ times a non whitespace character followed by `flowers.com.au`
- `(\w+(?:\.[^\s,.#]+)+)` Use your regex in a capturing group and use that in the replacement

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0aaLLj/1)

Note that your negated character class `[^\s,\.^#]` could be written as `[^\s,.#]+`

Comment: thank you so much mate! That worked a treat! I really appreciate your explanation and makes perfect sense thanks :)

Comment: I know this may sound silly but I am still struggling to understand why \w+(?!aword) doesn't simply look for a string NOT followed by a substring?

Comment: @Bass That is because you are first matching 1+ word characters and then assert that what is on the right is not `aword` but you have already matched 1+ word characters which will also match `aword`. So on the right can not be any more word characters and the assertion will be true and `\w+` will match.

Maybe these examples can make it more clear when you try to match `a` followed by the negative lookahead or when you try to match 1+ word characters followed by the lookahead: [example1](https://regex101.com/r/u8XTRV/1) and [example2](https://regex101.com/r/GqLVX0/1)

Comment: To read about lookarounds, you could check 
[this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) and [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: fourth kind, thank you so much it starting to make sense and I appreciate you taking the time to setup some examples really makes it clearer! Cheers :)